# Question about a derivation from the maximum principal

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $f$ is a complex analytic function from the open connected set $\Omega$ into $\mathbb{C}$.

The maximum principal tells us that if $|f|$ attains a local maximum in $\Omega$ then $f$ is constant on $\Omega$.

I'm wondering; suppose that for some compact set $\emptyset \neq C$ we have $C \subset \Omega$.

Then since $|f|$ is continuous on $C$ it attains a maximum there, say at $z_0 \in C$.

So if $z_0$ is in the interior of $C$ we can find an open and connected ball $B$ s.t $z_0 \in B \subset C$, from which we decude that $f$ is constant on $B$ and hence on smaller balls too.

This seems an incredible trait; is my reasoning correct? Can we say something when $z_0$ isn't in the interior of $C$?

Comment: I didn't understand exactly what you are asking? And it not cumpulsory for $C$ to have an interior like we can take $[o,1] \subset \mathbb{C}$ which is compact but have empty interior.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $f$ is non constant and let $z_0 \in C$ be an interior point of $C$ with properties you mentioned,

then $f$ is constant on open ball $B$.

But (as $\Omega$ is connected) by identity theorem,

$f$ is constant function which gives contradiction to our assumption.

Hence for non constants analytic function $f$ on $\Omega$, $z_0$ can’t be interior point of compact set $C$.